# Deploy Laravel 4.2 using only FTP in a shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-4, web-hosting

I have two directory named `daatjApp` and `daatj` in `root` directory. `daatjApp` where I have kept all my directory except `public` directory and `daatj` where I have kept all files of public directory.

And my index.php is

```
<?php

 require __DIR__.'/../daatjApp/bootstrap/autoload.php';


 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../daatjApp/bootstrap/start.php';


 $app->run();
```

And my paths.php is

```
  <?php

 return array(



'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',


'public' => __DIR__.'/../../daatj',

'base' => __DIR__.'/../',


 'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',

 );
```

When I access url `www.myproject.com/daatj` it shows nothing. I can not understand what I have done wrong.

Note: All directory are in root directory